# Struggling to convert SQL to LINQ

Tags: c#, .net, sql, linq, linq-to-sql

I have a Linq expression that (for northwind) gets the total qty ordered per product for customer id 'ALFKI'

```
from od in db.OrderDetails
    where od.Order.CustomerID == "ALFKI"
    group od by od.Product.ProductName into g1
    select new { ProductName = g1.Key, Total = g1.Sum(od => od.Quantity) }
```

This is fine but to fully understand Linq, I want to try and formulate the expression in a world where Linq2Sql doesn't nicely build the property bridges through foreign keys.

For instance, in the above expression, I'm accessing od.Order.CustomerID. I want to assume that od.OrderID is as far as I can go.

Looking at the SQL for the expression, I have:

```
SELECT SUM(CONVERT(Int,[t0].[Quantity])) AS [Total], [t2].[ProductName]
FROM [Order Details] AS [t0]
INNER JOIN [Orders] AS [t1] ON [t1].[OrderID] = [t0].[OrderID]
INNER JOIN [Products] AS [t2] ON [t2].[ProductID] = [t0].[ProductID]
WHERE [t1].[CustomerID] = @p0
GROUP BY [t2].[ProductName]
```

This is as far as I've managed to get:

```
from od in db.OrderDetails
    join o in db.Orders on od.OrderID equals o.OrderID
    join p in db.Products on od.ProductID equals p.ProductID
    where o.CustomerID == "ALFKI"
    group od by od.ProductID into g1
    select new { ProductName = g1.Key, Total = g1.Sum(od => od.Quantity) }
```

This is almost there but g1.Key is referring to the ProductID. I can't seem to get at the ProductName and the order quantity at the same time.

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try creating a new anonymous type for your group by:

```
from od in db.OrderDetails
    join o in db.Orders on od.OrderID equals o.OrderID
    join p in db.Products on od.ProductID equals p.ProductID
where o.CustomerID == "ALFKI"
group od by new { p.ProductID, p.ProductName } into g1
select new { 
    ProductName = g1.Key.ProductName, 
    Total = g1.Sum(od => od.Quantity) }
```

Comment: Thanks, that's great though it needs a slight correction. It should be { od.ProductID, p.ProductName }.

Comment: Ah, ok... I have updated the answer.  I believe it should work with `{ p.ProductID, p.ProductName }`.  Does it?

Comment: I knew about composite keys but it hadn't occurred to me to refer to fields from the other entities. One more question. Is it somehow possible to refer to the whole join (od, o and p) through a new variable and then iterate through that? ie. myJoin = (od, o, p); from item in MyJoin ...

Comment: I forgot to say before that it does work. I'd already tested before I posted my comment.

Comment: Hmm... I'm not sure I understand your question. Perhaps you could post it as a new question with a full example.  That will make the question easier to understand.  Or just give it a try and see if it works for you.

Comment: See my answer for what I was struggling to put into words.

Answer (score 0):

As well as Kevin's answer, using a composite key, I also managed to do it another way:

```
from item in (from od in db.OrderDetails
                  join o in db.Orders on od.OrderID equals o.OrderID
                  join p in db.Products on od.ProductID equals p.ProductID
                  where o.CustomerID == "ALFKI"
                  select new {ProductName = p.ProductName, Quantity = od.Quantity }
              )
              group item by item.ProductName into g1
              select new {ProductName = g1.Key, Total = g1.Sum(od=>od.Quantity) }
```

More generally, if you want to splice all the joins together and refer to any field:

```
from item in (from od in db.OrderDetails
                 join o in db.Orders on od.OrderID equals o.OrderID
                 join p in db.Products on od.ProductID equals p.ProductID
                 where o.CustomerID == "ALFKI"
                 select new { p, od }
             )
             group item by item.p.ProductName into g1
             select new { ProductName = g1.Key, Total = g1.Sum(all => all.od.Quantity)}
```